# Phalcon PhP - is there an EOF for model::find

Tags: php, phalcon, eof, phalcon-orm

I'm writing a piece of code and in it I would like to know if the result of a find if empty or not. Here is my piece of code:

```
public function signatureAction()
{
    $info = $this->session->get('current_quote');
    $object_list = ApplicationSignatureFile::find(array('conditions' => 'application_id = ?1 AND quote_id = ?2',
        'bind' => [
            1 => $info['application_id'],
            2 => $info['quote_id'],
        ]));

    $this->view->setVar('object_list', $object_list);
    if ($object_list) {
        $this->view->setVar('has_files',true);
    } else {
        $this->view->setVar('has_files',false);
    }
}
```

What I don't know yet if how to check if `$object_list` is EOF so I can set the `has_files` variable better. Currently it is not working. How can I do that in a controller and in a `.volt` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty strange actually. Using `findFirst` or any other ORM method returns `false` on fail, however using `find` does not.

A simple workaround in your case would be to use the `count` method on the result set:

```
$test = \Models\Objects::find([
    'conditions' => 'is_active = 42'
]);
if ($test->count()) {
    print('I have records with is_active = 42');
    d($test->toArray());
} else {
    print('I do not have any records with is_active = 42');
}
```

Comment: I think this can be a bug with phalcon and php 7, had it too but didn't have time to check what is causing it.

Comment: @Juri tested at home with Phalcon 2, and PHP 5.6.

Comment: @Juri, I don't think this is a bug, but rather intended behaviour. `find` return an empty `ResultsetInterface` (a _loopable_ object), it is meant to be traversed. For example; if you do `$findResultset->getFirst()`, it will get your assumed value of `false`.